# ElasticSearch: scoped aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate

My understanding is that I can apply aggs to the scope of the query.
If I run the query only, it brings back 21K hits. However, when I add aggs to it, it comes back empty. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you,

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
         { "term": {"app.raw": "ME"} }
        ,{ "term": {"cat.raw": "IV"} }
        ,{ "term": {"sub.raw": "Act"} }
      ]
    }
  }
,
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_users": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "login",
        "precision_threshold": 1000
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Can you also show a couple documents that are supposed to match? And possible also your mapping type.

Comment: I do not have access to _mapping

Comment: Here is the example of query result: `{
    "took": 3,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 25,
        "successful": 25,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1439,
        "max_score": 11.301117,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "ss-2015.06.14",
                "_type": "m",
                    "login_id": "Victor.Bach@versus.com",
     ..........
     ......
                    "event_kind": 1
                },
    ...............
   }
  }
}`

Comment: Please update your question with all the info that can be useful for us to help you. To get the mapping: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/ss-2015.06.14/m/_mapping`. Please share

Comment: Val, here is what I get: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>403 Forbidden</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Forbidden</h1>
        <p>You don't have permission to access /ES/ss-2015.06.14/_mapping
on this server.</p>
    </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

Because your request to elasticsearch has an "aggs" parameter, the "size" parameter defaults to 0 and query results are not returned, only aggregation results.

Add a "size" field with whatever value you want to the topmost object in the query to also return search hits, e.g.

```
{
  query: {
    ...
  },
  size: 42,
  aggs: {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I am running this search in Postman (Chrome). I've added size:1000, but have no aggs displayed. In fact it displays 10 hits only. I believe it's default.